# make an image display over a html form

Tags: html

I have this HTML Form (in a table)

```
<style type="text/css">
form {
    text-align:center;
    background:url(padlock_closed.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>

<form>
<table width="600" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <td width="199"><strong>Forename</strong></td>
    <td width="366"><input type="text" name="forename" size="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Surname</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="surname" size="50" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" size="50" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

It currently has an image background but i want it to look like its displaying in front of the form rather than behind and make the image centre too?

whats the best way of doing this?

Comment: If you do it, you won't be able to click on the form's element. An opaque element if still "catching" all mouse events.

Comment: thats fine - the form is okay to be disabled

Comment: Why wouldn't you rather just put the image behind the form, and possibly make the form itself opaque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your approach, do you want a button to be clicked first so that the image will appear or is it already there?

To make the image opaque, you can use CSS3 and 'filter' for IE compatibility:

```
#id-of-image {
 opacity: 0.8;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80); //IE support
}
```

(You can change the values)

To make the image put above the form, use css positioning (relative, absolute, relative)

Comment: @charlie hi charlie, it's better if you make the form itself opaque rather than the image :) You will receive better results. Just apply the css to the form and everything within the form will become opaque.

Comment: so i have added this CSS to apply to the form: form {
 text-align:center;
 background:url(padlock_closed.png) no-repeat;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
} but its also making the form background image opaque?

Comment: @charlie Place the form inside a <div> that has the same height and width of your form or inside a <table> if your form stretches with no determined height/width. Then assign the background-image to the div/table, not the form. :)

Comment: ah yes - works great. now i have this: form {
 text-align:center;
 opacity: 0.5;
 filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}

.div_form {
 margin:0 auto 0 auto;
 background:url(padlock_closed.png) no-repeat;
}

how can i centre the image over the form/table?

Comment: @charlie Apply 'background-position: center center;' to the <div>. Also as a sidenote, if you want to make you image FILL the div no matter the size, apply 'background-size: cover;'. If I have answered your question, please vote this as the answer :)

Comment: excellent  - thank you. in my table i have the background colours #666666 on the labels (next to the input elements) so when the form is opaque you can still see those background colours over the image?    any ideas?

Comment: @charlie Apply 'background: none;' to the labels to remove the background color.

Comment: @charlie If you have no more questions please choose this as the best answer for the effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use jquery pop up.

Add div like

```
<div id="dialog-modal-loading" style="display:none;">
   <img src="images/your_image.gif">
</div>
```

Call a javascript function to pop up. Change height and width as your wish.

```
function call_dialog(){   
     $( "#dialog-modal-loading" ).dialog({
       height: 180,
       width: 180,
       modal: true,      
       closeOnEscape: false,
       resizable: false,
       position: 'center',
       beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
       dialogClass: "noclose"
     });
     $('.ui-dialog').css('opacity','0.2');
}
```